# Спарсить данные с .txt файла из github репозитория на c#

Tags: c#, парсер, github, repository

Как мне можно получить текст написанный в моем репозитории в .txt файле?
У меня в репозитории в .txt файле написан следующий текст - "Тест1". Как мне через код на c# получать текст в этом файле и при том, чтобы другие этого не могли(только владелец репозитория).
Мне нужен парсинг именно с github репозитория.

Comment: смысл парсить файл из собственного репозитория? Но вообще вы можете 1) установить SSH ключи ваши 2) склонироать репозиторий себе 3) Распарсить файл.

Comment: а нельзя прям текстом, а не 'скачивать' файл?

Comment: я не понимаю, что значит "прям текстом". Если вы по HTTPS хотите скачать, то можете поглядеть в сторону [raw githubusercontent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779197/how-to-link-files-directly-from-github-raw-github-com), но я не уверен, что он работает с привантыми репозиторями

Comment: можете опубликовать репозиторий на страницах гитхаб. в этом случае любое изменение в репозитории приведет через несколько минут обновление гитхаб страницы. ну а считать данные из веб программно несложно. конечно это не то, что вы хотите... можно посмотреть в сторону автоматической публикации куда-нибудь еще (например на ваше облако)